# ¿Como obtener la ruta de un archivo almacenada en un servidor local en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Para mi proyecto necesito cargar un archivo que se encuentra almacenado en el servidor local, mi ruta la estoy ingresando de la siguiente manera.

```
string Ruta_Carpeta = "\\servidor\\Dllo SW\\Secciones Predefinidas - Columnas";
string Ruta_Completa = "\\servidor\\Dllo SW\\Secciones Predefinidas - Columnas\\Secciones.sec";

            DirectoryInfo directory_seccion = new DirectoryInfo(Ruta_Carpeta);

            foreach (FileInfo Archivo in directory_seccion.GetFiles())
            {
                if (Archivo.Name == Ruta_Archivo)
                {
                    Encuentra = true;
                    FunctionsProject.Deserealizar_Secciones(Ruta_Completa, ref Lista_Secciones);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (Encuentra == false)
            {
                Lista_Secciones = new CLista_Secciones();
                Crear_Secciones();
                FunctionsProject.Serializar_Secciones(Ruta_Completa, Lista_Secciones);
            }
```

Pero al cargar la variable me esta indicando que su raiz se encuentra en el disco C, que debo de hacer para que el codigo obtenga el archivo pero desde el servidor.
Gracias

Comment: Hola, que tipo de aplicaciíón es Windows Forms o Web Forms?

Comment: Windows Forms @RafaelAcosta

Answer (score 0):

La solucion a mi problema fue escribir la variable de la siguiente forma:

```
string Ruta_Carpeta = @"\\servidor\\Dllo SW\\Secciones Predefinidas - Columnas";
```

Comment: Podrías explicar el porqué de la solución a tu pregunta?, ser algo mas amplio en la explicación. Me interesa saber porqué con una **@** delante del **path** te toma la ruta del servidor, por que veo que tus rutas ya empiezan por "**\\servidor**", no lo entiendo.

Comment: El @ se utiliza para interpretar literalmente el contenido de la cadena